# jquery - hide css if select dropdown is chosen

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic form that creates  drop downs and increments the names correctly.  What i need to do is hide a text box if the user selects a certain dropdown value.  This i can do, but what i need help on is hiding the right thing as the names are incremental.

```
$("select[id^=Profession]").change(function() {
 if(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val() == "2") {
    jQuery("#ADA_1").hide();
} else {
    jQuery("#ADA_1").show();
};  });
```

Working Sample: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nVHX/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select[id^=Profession]").change(function() {
 var id = $(this).attr('id').split('Profession')[1];
 if(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val() == "2") {
    jQuery("#ADA_"+id).hide();
 } else {
    jQuery("#ADA_"+id).show();
 }
});
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5nVHX/6/)

Comment: Using the 'split' options isn't one I had thought of.  Excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("select[id^=Profession]").change(function () {
    index = $(this).attr('id').substr(-1);
    if (jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val() == "2") {
        jQuery("#ADA_"+index).hide();
    } else {
        jQuery("#ADA_"+index).show();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5nVHX/3/)**

Comment: what if the number is 10 like Profession10?

Comment: I was actually thinking that too.  In that case this suggestion wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
$("select[id^=Profession]").change(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val() == "2") {
        jQuery(this).parent().next("[id^=ADA_]").hide();
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().next("[id^=ADA_]").show();
    }
});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/LqCuA/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[id^=Profession]").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Profession', '');
    if (jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val() == "2") {
        jQuery("#ADA_"+id).hide();
    } else {
        jQuery("#ADA_"+id).show();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5nVHX/7/)